# Using single quotation mark as character

Tags: c

I want to ask whether we can use the single quotation mark " ' " as a character in c language. If yes how?

I tried like this `id[i]=='''`but errors occurred.

Comment: Try using `'\''`.

Comment: `char charVariable = 39;` or `char charVariable = 047;` or `char charVariable = 0x27;` also work just fine. See [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) However, for readability in a comparison, the escaped character constant is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

```
char charVariable = '\'';
```

it works like this

Comment: char charVariable = '\'';

it works like this